# Android getOnTouchListener with API version >= 15

Tags: android, reflection, listener, field

I need to know if there has been set an OnTouchListener to a view.
Following code works fine below api level 15.

```
    public static boolean isSetOnTouchListener_v8(View v) {
        try {

            Class<View> clazz = (Class<View>) Class.forName("android.view.View");
            Field f = clazz.getDeclaredField("mOnTouchListener");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            if (f.get(v) == null)   {
                return false;
            }

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Now I need the same method for api level 15 and above.

I tried the following code, but it's not working. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
public static boolean isSetOnTouchListener_v15(View v) {
    try {
        Object listenerInfo = getListenerInfo(v);

        if (listenerInfo != null) {
            Class<? extends Object> clazz = listenerInfo.getClass();
            Field f = clazz.getDeclaredField("mOnTouchListener");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            if (f.get(listenerInfo) == null) return false;
        }

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}

private static Object getListenerInfo(View v) {
    Field f = null;
    try {
        f = View.class.getDeclaredField("mListenerInfo");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        return (Object) f.get(v);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```